# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'ss.tbl_node' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

//tbl_gw is created , but when i try create tbl_node it show an error

`ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'ss.tbl_node' (errno: 150)`

My sql is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_gw(id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,gid varchar(24),vid varchar(24),primary key(id));

CREATE TABLE tbl_node(nid SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, gid int(10),primary key(nid) ,FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES tbl_gw(gid)) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Is the default Engine InnoDB? Perhaps tbl_gw should also have 'ENGINE = INNODB' ?

Comment: i had tried , but again i got same problem

Comment: Your column `tbl_node.gid` is of type INT(10), references the column `tbl_gw.gid` of the type VARCHAR(24). This column isn't even indexed. I'm assuming it should rather reference `tbl_gw.id` instead.

Comment: you mean something like CREATE TABLE tbl_node(nid SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, gid int(10),primary key(nid) ,FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES tbl_gws.id) ENGINE=INNODB;

Answer (score 0):

The datatype of Foreign key and the key that points to it should be the same.

In your case

> CREATE TABLE tbl_gw(id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,gid
>   varchar(24),vid varchar(24),primary key(id));
>
> CREATE TABLE tbl_node(nid SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   gid int(10),primary key(nid) ,FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES
>   tbl_gw(gid)) ENGINE=INNODB;

**gid is of type varchar in TABLE tbl_gw which is not the same as type int in TABLE tbl_node**

make either type same as other and it'll work